# Cisco AnyConnect Plus license based on users

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, vpn, license

Cisco AnyConnect Plus license terms are based on user count and not simultaneous connected sessions. When it said based on users, does that mean the total connected number of users or a total account created on an ASA?

For example:

We have 50 employee and only 20 employees are going to use the VPN. Should I need to buy a licence for 50 Users or 25 Users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [AnyConnect Licensing Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/anyconnect-secure-mobility-client/200191-AnyConnect-Licensing-Frequently-Asked-Qu.html#anc7):

> Q. How do I determine how many licenses to purchase?
>
> A. The AnyConnect Plus and Apex model is based on total authorized
>   users **that will make use of any AnyConnect service**, not simultaneous
>   connections (either on a per-ASA or shared basis) **and not total active
>   remote access users**.

(emphasis mine)

So you need licences only for the employee that will use the VPN.